# how to check textbox value availability on server without the form submitting using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

basically i have a form and in that form i have a username textbox with a submit button. now what i want is that before we submit the form i want to send the text value to server so the server could check if the username has not been taken by any other user and then submit the form, based on research i had, i found this tutorial useful https://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery, altough this tutorial is using php for server coding and i am using java servlet but my ajax script never gets to execute.

here is my code:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-     scale=1">    
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js">                  </script>

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

// process the form
 $('form').submit(function(event) {

event.preventDefault();
alert('hello');
// get the form data
// there are many ways to get this data using jQuery (you can use the class           or id also)
var formData = {
    'username'             : $('input[name=UserName]').val(),
};
alert('hello');
// process the form
$.ajax({
    type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
    url         : '../postr', // the url where we want to POST
    data        : formData, // our data object
    dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
                encode          : true
})
    // using the done promise callback
    .done(function(data) {

        // log data to the console so we can see
        console.log(data); 

        // here we will handle errors and validation messages
    });

// stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
 });

 });

  </script>
 <form class="Registration_Form" id="Registration_Form" action="../postr" method="POST">
 <div id="Registeration_Username_DIV" class="Registeration_Username_DIV">
        <input type="text" id="Registeration_Username_box"      class="Registeration_Username_box"
            name="UserName" onblur="Usernameerrorfunc(this, 'Usernameerror_spn', 'Usernamenowallow_spn');" maxlength="30" onclick="textboxfocus(this)"/>
    </div>
 <div class="Registration_Submit_Div">
        <input type="submit" value="submit" id="SumbitForm_btn" class="SumbitForm_btn" name="Submit_btn"/>
    </div>

 </form>
 <script>function Usernameerrorfunc(field, errordiv, Notallowcharserror_SPN)     {
if (field.value == '') {            
    field.style.borderColor = "red";
    document.getElementById(Notallowcharserror_SPN).style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById(errordiv).style.visibility = "visible";
} else if(!field.value.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9~`!@#\(\.)]+$/)){
    field.style.borderColor = "red";
    document.getElementById(Notallowcharserror_SPN).style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById(errordiv).style.visibility = "hidden";
} else {
    field.style.borderColor = "rgb(150,150,150)";
    document.getElementById(errordiv).style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById(Notallowcharserror_SPN).style.visibility = "hidden";
}
 }</script>
```

as you can see in my ajax script i have an alert() which it should pop up hello but it never does

Comment: Actually, you have two alerts inside the submit handler, not inside the ajax call, are you saying the submit event never fires ?

Comment: yes that is what i meant

Comment: Both alerts work just fine in a [simple test](https://jsfiddle.net/h6q9vr2s/). Have you checked the console for errors.

Comment: i just tried it, it doesn't pop me here and there is no console error too. can you read through the code once

Comment: instead of alerts, try using console.log and check the console, i think maybe your browser is blocking alerts, because i tested it on a fiddle and works just fine.

Comment: just tried it no luck

Comment: my file extension is jsp not html do you think it have something to do with that?

Comment: by submitting button it just goes to postr